# Parameterization of a line segment for a line integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Image: https://i.gyazo.com/ca53a195685574c842f8e8ed2ae30c69.jpg

My question is on the line below where it says "Along the path...": I have no idea where that x+z component came from. I'm sure it's from the parameterization of the straight segment, but I'm not sure what process you use to get that. Can someone show steps? Thank you.

Comment: Actually it looks like a typo.  I think $\vec F$ is supposed to be $\langle -y, x+z, xy\rangle$ and they just left off the $+z$ when they defined it.

Comment: The straight line part of the path has nothing to do with the integral over the semicircular bit of the path.  The only explanation I can see for why an extra bit shows up in the $\vec F\cdot d\vec r$ bit is there is a typo (which happens fairly frequently in both textbooks and professors' notes/ homework).

Comment: Of course, we can parameterize the line from $(0, 2, \pi)$ to $(0, -2, \pi) as x= 0, y= 2- 4t. $z= \pi$ with t going from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out @Bye_World was correct -- it was a typo. F was supposed to originally be given as < whatever, x+z, whatever> and was incorrectly given as < whatever, x, whatever>. At least it explains why I was so confused.